# Why is there repetition of the measure words in 一把把小扇子 and 一枚枚邮票?

Tags: usage, measure-word

This is from my 3-rd grade Chinese 语文 book (transcript is [here](http://www.lbx777.com/multimedia/kwld/read_051.htm)):

> 秋天的雨，有一盒五彩缤纷的颜料。你看，它把黄色给了银杏树，黄黄的叶子像**一把把小扇子**，扇哪扇哪，扇走了夏天的炎热。它把红色给了枫树，红红的枫叶像**一枚枚邮票**，飘哇飘哇，邮来了秋天的凉爽。金黄色是给田野的，看，田野像金色的海洋。橙红色是给果树的，橘子、柿子你挤我碰，争着要人们去摘呢！菊花仙子得到的颜色就更多了，紫红的、淡黄的、雪白的……美丽的菊花在秋雨里频频点头。

**Question**: Why is there repetition of the measure words in 一把把小扇子 and 一枚枚邮票?

I would guess this is for poetic reasons, but I'm not sure.  I've never seen this before.

The use above seems different to the question [What is the meaning of "一把把" on "他更是一把把她的书包给枪了过去“？](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/21100/) where it seems only the first 把 is the measure word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question [What does the second "幅” mean in the following sentence?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25785/what-does-the-second-%e5%b9%85-mean-in-the-following-sentence/25787#25787)

My answer there should be applicable here too.

> *"一幅幅" in "一幅幅美丽的山水画" mainly means 'one after another'*

With the same logic,  一把把小扇子 and 一枚枚邮票 means "one small fan after another" and "one stamp after another" (meaning many fans and many stamps)

Comment: Thanks!  It didn't come up when I searched.